# VB, how to solve this error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have some problem in my code :

```
For i = 0 To Split(awal, vbCrLf).Length - 1
    For j = 0 To Split(hasil(i), " ").Length - 1
        hasil1(j) = hasil(i).Split(" ")
    Next j
Next i
```

it comes with error :

> "Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to
>   'String' " in the " hasil1(j) = hasil(i).Split(" ") " section.

can anyone explain to me how to solve this, please?

Comment: The first parameter of **Split** function must be a string.

Comment: yes, hasil() and hasil1() is a string array
for example the text is
"abcd 123
efgh 11
ijkl"
now in hasil() we got ("abcd 123","efgh 11","ijkl")
and i want to separate the element in hasil() so that 
hasil1() =("abcd","123","efgh","11","ijkl")

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you are trying to add an Array to a String Array.

The `Split()` function returns an `Array` and this is causing the error.

If your intention is to get an Array of Arrays, make that variables that way, if not, what was the purpose on using `Split(" ")` on that line?

**Edit:**

Based on you comment:

You will have to loop once more for this to be complete:

```
Dim it As Integer
Dim tmp() As String
it = 0

For i = 0 To Split(awal, vbCrLf).Length - 1
    For j = 0 To Split(hasil(i), " ").Length - 1
        tmp = hasil(i).Split(" ")

        For k = 0 To tmp.Length - 1
            hasil1(it) = tmp(k)
            it += 1
        Next
    Next j
Next i
```

My skills in VB.Net are rusted and I'm not in my dev machine, so try this and let me know if something doesn't work.

Comment: thank's for helping me rcdmk, but what is the tmp variable datatype ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you initialize your hasil array,
however, you could simplify your code using a List(Of String) in this way

```
Dim hasil() as String = New String() {"abcd 123","efgh 11","ijkl"}
Dim hasil1 as List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
For i = 0 To hasil.Length - 1 
    hasil1.AddRange(hasil(i).Split(" "))
Next i
```

You can allways convert it back to a string array with:

```
Dim s() as String = hasil1.ToArray()
```